# How to create a webapi that allows dynamic objects with validation

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-5.0

I'm trying to create a webapi that receives a array of json object in the body, like so:

```c#
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Example([FromBody] JObject[] objects) {}
```

Every object that is being send needs to have an property `Id` and `ObjectId`, how can I validate the objects.

I tried to create an class with the properties Id and ObjectId, that inherits from `DynamicObject`, to allow additional properties. But that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: `JObjects` have a `ContainsKey` method, is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom Attribute and add that to each Method or Class.  The attribute class will fire before the method logic.  For example, a "RouteParameterValidator" would roughly look like this...

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters;

namespace You.Custom.Namespace
{

    public class ValidateRouteParametersAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
           
            // validate route fields 
            string routeParameterValue = filterContext.ActionArguments["some_key"] as string;
            // do validation 
            if (routeParameterValue == null){
            }
                throw new InvalidParameterValueException("no way!");
            }
       }
    }
}
```

Then use it in the controller like this...

```
[ApiController]
[ValidateRouteParameters]
public class MyController : ControllerBase
{
  ... 
}
```

Then extend the attribute for additional properties.  I have my attribute use custom "Rules" and each Rule has a different set of require fields and/or lengths.